# Ada in R giving me single classification

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, adaboost

I am using the function ada in R, and I'm having a little difficulty. I have training data that looks like this

```
   V13         V15        V17        V19
1  0.017241379 0.471264368 0.01449275 0.24637681
2  0.255813953 0.011627907 0.06849315 0.05479452
3  0.040000000 0.400000000 0.06000000 0.10000000
4  0.500000000 0.000000000 0.05128205 0.00000000
5  0.102040816 0.367346939 0.05769231 0.19230769
6  0.561403509 0.105263158 0.11111111 0.00000000
7  0.300813008 0.048780488 0.12222222 0.03333333
8  0.000000000 0.714285714 0.14285714 0.07142857
9  0.328947368 0.013157895 0.01492537 0.00000000
10 0.536585366 0.060975610 0.16071429 0.03571429
11 0.338461538 0.030769231 0.11764706 0.03921569
12 0.033898305 0.322033898 0.11764706 0.21568627
```

This is what I have stored in the variable

```
matrix.x
```

Then I have the response variables y

```
    y
1   1
2  -1
3   1
4  -1
5   1
6  -1
7  -1
8   1
9  -1
10 -1
11 -1
12  1
```

I simply run the following:

```
ada.obj = ada(matrix.x, matrix.y)
```

And then

```
ada.pred = predict(ada.obj, matrix.x)
```

And for some reason, I get a matrix with all 1s or all -1s. What am I doing wrong? Ideally, I want the ada.pred to spit out the exact classifications of the training data.

Thanks.

Also how would I go about using the AdabOost1.M1 function in caret package of R?

Comment: I very much doubt you mean the programming language [tag:ada], so I’ve removed the tag.

Comment: @SimonWright: yes, [tag:adaboost] is one type of ML algorithm, nothing to do with Ada language. Also tagged this [tag:classification]